# How to Get SQL Where node expr in ANTLR using Java

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to fetch where clause using Antlr parser for sql query in java. I dnt know how to get. Can any one tellme the answer....Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT student.name,
       student.student_id,
       event.date,
       event.event_id,
       event.type
FROM student, event
LEFT JOIN score
    ON student.student_id = score.student_id AND
       event.event_id = score.event_id
WHERE score.score IS NULL
ORDER BY student.student_id,
         event.event_id;
```

I want score.score IS NULL as answer.

I have tried like this...

```
    System.out.println("hello join");
    SQLiteLexer lexer = new SQLiteLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(subQuery));
    SQLiteParser parser = new SQLiteParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> joinQueryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    final ArrayList<String> functionNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> joinTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> joinConsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ParseTree tree = parser.select_stmt();
    final TableFamily tableFamily=new TableFamily();

    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new SQLiteBaseListener() {         
        @Override
        public void enterExpr(SQLiteParser.ExprContext ctx) {
            if (ctx.function_name() != null) {
                functionNames.add(ctx.function_name().getText());
            }
            if (ctx.column_name() != null) {
                columnNames.add(ctx.column_name().getText());                       
            }   
        }                       
        public void enterSelect_stmt(SQLiteParser.Select_stmtContext ctx){
            //System.out.println(ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery(0).getText());             
            if(ctx.select_or_values()!=null){
                int len=ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().size();
                //System.out.println("len is "+len);
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++){                     
                    boolean aliasFlag=false;
                    tableNames.add(ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_name().getText());  
                    tableFamily.setTableName(ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_name().getText());
                    //System.out.println("Table-> "+ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_name().getText());

                    if(ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_alias()!=null){
                        //System.out.println("Table Alias-> "+ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_alias().getText());
                        tableFamily.setTableAlias(ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_name().getText());
                        aliasFlag=true;
                    }
                    //System.out.println("flag-> "+aliasFlag);
                    for(int j=0;j<ctx.select_or_values().get(0).result_column().size();j++){
                        String columns=ctx.select_or_values().get(0).result_column().get(j).getText();
                        if(columns.contains("(")&&columns.contains("")){
                            //System.out.println(columns);
                            columns=columns.substring(columns.indexOf("(")+1, columns.indexOf(")"));
                        }
                        //System.out.println("columns-> "+columns);
                        String columnArr[]=columns.split("\\.");
                        //System.out.println(columnArr[0]+" %% "+columnArr[1]);
                        //System.out.println("check-> "+ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_alias().getText().equals(columnArr[0]));
                        if(aliasFlag && ctx.select_or_values().get(0).join_clause().table_or_subquery().get(i).table_alias().getText().equals(columnArr[0])){
                            System.out.println("col1 "+columnArr[1]);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("col "+columns);
                        }
                    }                       
                    System.out.println();
                }
                for(int k=0;k<ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_operator().size();k++){
                    System.out.println("Join Type-> "+ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_operator().get(k).getText());
                    joinTypeList.add(ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_operator().get(k).getText());
                }
                for(int l=0;l<ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_constraint().size();l++){
                    System.out.println("Join Constraint-> "+ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_constraint().get(l).expr().getText());
                    joinConsList.add(ctx.select_or_values(0).join_clause().join_constraint().get(l).expr().getText());
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }               
        }                       
    }, tree);
    joinQueryMap.put("\nFunction Names", functionNames);
    joinQueryMap.put("\nColumn Names", columnNames);
    joinQueryMap.put("\nTable Names", tableNames);  
    joinQueryMap.put("\nJoin Type", joinTypeList);
    joinQueryMap.put("\nJoin Constraint", joinConsList);

    /*System.out.println("sFunction Names "+functionNames);
    System.out.println("sColumn Names "+columnNames);
    System.out.println("Table Names "+tableNames);*/
    System.out.println("tab "+tableFamily.getTableName());
    System.out.println("tab1 "+tableFamily.getTableAlias());
    return joinQueryMap;
```

Comment: `FROM student, event` ... be aware that this deprecated (read: really old) syntax, and it possibly means that you are doing a cross join between these two tables, or at least the type of join you are doing may be less restrictive than what you intend.

Comment: I need from the simple one too like...select id,name from table where id=10;  from this one i need where clause using antlrparser.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the grammar you used and you didn't tell us what your problem is (do you get wrong results, no results, doesn't compile, whatever). So I have to guess a bit here.

First, don't use the `enterXXX` functions in your listeners for getting parse results. On enter things are set up, but nothing is parsed in that subtree so far. So, usually you use the `exitXXX` functions instead. Then, if you are only interested in the where clause look in your grammar. There is probably a rule for `where` (let's say `where_clause`). You can write an exit listener function exactly for this:

```
public void exitWhere_clause(SQLiteParser.Where_clauseContext ctx) {
  // Handle here the expression you are after.
}
```

Now you have different options. Diving down the expression subtree manually is a tedious task, so I recommend that you create another listener, which only deals with expressions. Instantiate this as a sublistener in the where clause function above to walk only the where expression (don't use this for the entire parse tree or you will have to check the context constantly - as expressions can occur in various places). With the local expression listener instead you can be 100% sure you only parse expression parts in a where clause.

Comment: I am new to antlr, so please answer me that how to write own listener for where clause, groupby etc...

Comment: You don't need an own listener for your where clause (you need one for the expression in it, however). Just add another override in your main listener above (the exact syntax depends on your grammar). Then in that overriden function you can create another listener and start a local walk (`ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new SQLiteBaseListener() {...` but use only `where` context. Override there the expr clause (or other rules used by that which are closer to what you want), which should exactly give you the needed info.